# How to give custom name to http_server_requests* related metrics for a spring boot rest api

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-ec2, prometheus, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

In my application I have multiple Rest APIs. By using @Timed annotation , I am getting http_server_requests* metrics for those Rest API, which is fine.
My application is being deployed to AWS, so based on these metrics in cloudwatch, I need to monitor cloudwatch alarms and generate an alert in slack.

As per cloudwatch alarm syntax, it only takes metrics name ex :

```
ApplicationTargetGroup.metrics("http_server_requests_seconds_sum",{....})
```

With this approach issue is that I am getting data for all endpoints with this. But I want to get this data for a specific Rest API. How can I achieve that? Is there a way with in above syntax to do that? or some other method?

Or I was thinking of an option to get each Rest API http_server_requests_seconds* metrics under some unique name. Will that be ok? If yes, How I can achieve that?